# Use Python to make PDF forms read-only

Tags: python, pdf

How can I convert a PDF form into a read-only PDF for sending it to my client?

Currently I am doing this by opening each of the PDF forms in Mac Preview and printing to a PDF. This is a very time consuming process.

I am already using some python scripts to automate some of my project tasks. Is there is a python module, that I can use to make these PDF forms read-only in place of having to open each of them in preview?

Here is code I use to merge PDFs. It merges great but the merged forms are still fillable forms. I need them to be read-only.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

merger = PdfFileMerger()
merger.append(open("pdf1.pdf",'rb'))
merger.append(open("pdf2.pdf",'rb'))

merger.write("merged.pdf")
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you are working with currently?

Comment: I edited my post with some code that I'm using. It's not really a code that addresses the whole print to PDF issue though.

Answer (score 3):

Can be done by setting the ***permissions_flag*** parameter while writing the PDF using PyPDF2.

Ref: https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/PyPDF2/_writer.html#PdfWriter.encrypt

*Run Using: Python 3.10 & PyPDF 2.11*

Sample:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter

output_Writer = PdfFileWriter()

# This would give Read and Print only permissions to the PDF file.
output_Writer.encrypt(user_pwd='', owner_pwd='sample_password', permissions_flag=0b0100)
```

Notes...

```
:param unsigned int permissions_flag: permissions as described in
        TABLE 3.20 of the PDF 1.7 specification. A bit value of 1 means the
        permission is grantend. Hence an integer value of -1 will set all
        flags.
        Bit position 3 is for printing, 4 is for modifying content, 5 and 6
        control annotations, 9 for form fields, 10 for extraction of
        text and graphics.
```

Comment: Agreed. Navigating my way through stack-overflow.

Comment: Would you recommend I delete it and move it as a comment?

Comment: @Yunnosch and Prashanth, I recommend keeping this answer, since it is on the most upvoted and older question

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Reasonable. Does it make sense to close-vote the other question as dupe of this one? I will not, because I lack the technical understanding.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, apologies for the confusion. It took us sometime to find an answer for this so thought I'll write in one place and leave links of that in the other questions. And from an overview, the core-problem in all the questions seem to be the same. "How to write a read-only PDF using Python?"

Comment: You should now be able to flag questions as duplicate of this one. Be careful with that privilege, but it is the appropriate tool. Soon (50rep) you get the privilege to first ask a  clarification question in a comment on new questions, before you act.

Comment: [Help>Privileges](/help/privileges). Specifically: [flagging](/help/privileges/flag-posts) and [commenting](/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 1):

Read only permissions (print, edit, comment, etc) using pypdf, will not work under this approach, since the permissions_flag will not be enough to secure its permission in the pdf. You can still unlock the permissions using online tools like ilovepdf or something like that.